# How to bypass 3G bandwidth throttling and capping on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: internet

I'm using a 3G network connection and it was working like a charm until the government decided to slow it down in some areas of the country and now I'm starting to have headaches because of this. I want to know if there is any way I can boost my netspeed and increase or bypass 3G bandwidth cap!

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

> the government decided to slow it down in some areas of the country

This is done at the level of an ISP or if the government is the ISP at the level of the government you get your connection from. So it will be impossible to by-pass from your operating system.

> What should I do?

Use another form of connection or move to another country.

Comment: Bravo!! I don't think I can explain this simpler... Nicely done & dusted. :D